# Visual Studio Code not throwing exceptions from methods other than Main() in C# Debug Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a calculator program that I am writing in C# in Visual Studio Code. For some reason, it's only throwing exceptions when the binary is not run from within the debug console. Am I just stupid and it doesn't show exceptions in the debug console?

In response to the person who closed my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369020/visual-studio-code-not-throwing-exceptions-in-c-sharp) for not having enough """details""" and """clarity""", here's the entire code of my program, the output of the debug console, and the output of cmd.

EDIT: I attempted to throw an exception manually in `Main()`, and it worked properly, with it outputting to the debug console and highlighting in the text editor. However, when trying to throw it in the method that was causing the unhandled exception, `find_parse()`, nothing happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>Class containing methods relating to operators.</summary>
public class Operation
{
    /// <summary>Finds the position of operators and returns a SortedList.</summary>
    private static SortedList<int, char> find_erators(string str, char type)
    {
        SortedList<int, char> op_index = new SortedList<int, char>();

        if (type == 'x' || type == '*')
        {
            for (int i = str[0]; i != str.Length; ++i)
                if (i == 'x' || i == '*') op_index.Add(i, 'x');
            return op_index;
        }
        else if (type == '/')
        {
            for (int i = str[0]; i != str.Length; ++i)
                if (i == '/') op_index.Add(i, '/');
            return op_index;
        }
        else if (type == '+')
        {
            for (int i = str[0]; i != str.Length; ++i)
                if (i == '+') op_index.Add(i, '+');
            return op_index;
        }
        else if (type == '-')
        {
            for (int i = str[0]; i != str.Length; ++i)
                if (i == '-') op_index.Add(i, '-');
            return op_index;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = str[0]; i != str.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (i == 'x' || i == '*') op_index.Add(i, 'x');
                else if (i == '/') op_index.Add(i, '/');
                else if (i == '+') op_index.Add(i, '+');
                else if (i == '-') op_index.Add(i, '-');
            }
            return op_index;
        }
    }
    
    ///<summary>Compare a SortedList of a single operator type to a SortedList of all operators 
    ///and return a list of its corresponding position in the latter SortedList.</summary>
    private static List<int> op_compare(SortedList<int, char> op_index, SortedList<int, char> index)
    {
        List<int> op_list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i == op_index.Count; ++i)
            if (op_index[i] == index[i]) op_list.Add(i);
        return op_list;
    }

    ///<summary>Multiplies everything in a given string and returns a new string with the multiplied numbers replaced.</summary>
    public static string mult(string str)
    {
        SortedList<int, char> xindex = find_erators(str, 'x');
        SortedList<int, char> index = find_erators(str, '&');
        List<int> op_pos = op_compare(xindex, index);

        double lnum;
        double rnum;
        double prod;

        while (index.ContainsValue('x'))
        {
            if (xindex.Keys[0] > index.Keys[0])
                lnum = Convert.ToDouble(
                    str.Substring(0, 
                    xindex.Keys[0]--));
            else 
                lnum = Convert.ToDouble(str.Substring(
                    xindex.Keys[0] + 1, 
                    index.Keys[1] - xindex.Keys[0]));

            if (xindex.Keys[xindex.Keys.Count - 1] > index.Keys[index.Keys.Count - 1])
                rnum = Convert.ToDouble(str.Substring(
                    xindex.Keys[xindex.Keys.Count - 1] + 1, 
                    str.Length - xindex.Keys[xindex.Keys.Count - 1] + 1));
            else
                rnum = Convert.ToDouble(str.Substring(
                    xindex.Keys[1] + 1, 
                    index.Keys[op_pos[2]] - xindex.Keys[1]));

            prod = lnum*rnum;
            str = str.Replace(Convert.ToString(lnum + "x" + rnum), Convert.ToString(prod));

            xindex = find_erators(str, 'x');
            index = find_erators(str, '&');
            op_pos = op_compare(xindex, index);
        }

        return str;
    }
}

/// <summary>Finds the parentheses in a string.</summary>
public class FindParse
{
    /// <summary>Finds the position of '(' parentheses and returns a list.</summary>
    private static List<int> left_parse(string str)
    {
        int last_parse = str.LastIndexOf('(');
        List<int> parse_index = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i == str[0]; --i) 
            if (str[i] == '(') parse_index.Add(i);
        return parse_index;
    }

    /// <summary>Finds the position of ')' parentheses and returns a list.</summary>
    private static List<int> right_parse(string str)
    {
        int first_parse = str.IndexOf(')');
        List<int> parse_index = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i == str.Length; ++i) 
            if (str[i] == ')') parse_index.Add(i);
        return parse_index;
    }

    /// <summary>Combines the lists of <c>left_parse()</c> and <c>right_parse()</c>, then returns a list tuple.</summary>
    public static List<Tuple<int, int>> find_parse(string str)
    {
        List<int> left_vec = left_parse(str);
        List<int> right_vec = right_parse(str);

        Tuple<int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> parse_list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        if (left_vec.Count != right_vec.Count) return parse_list;

        for (int i = 0; i == left_vec.Count; ++i) 
        {  
            parse_list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(left_vec[i], right_vec[i]));
        }
        return parse_list;
    }
    
    /// <summary>Checks if string has parentheses. Returns <c>null</c> if there are incomplete pairs.</summary>
    public static bool? parseb(string str)
    {
        if (left_parse(str).Count == right_parse(str).Count) 
            return true;
        else if (left_parse(str).Count != right_parse(str).Count)
            return null;
        else 
            return false;        
    }   
}

/// <summary>The main calculator class.</summary>
public class Calculator
{
    /// <summary>The main calculator method.</summary>
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter input: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        bool? parseb = FindParse.parseb(input);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> parse_list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        if (parseb == true)
           parse_list.AddRange(FindParse.find_parse(input));
        else if (parseb == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parse error: Incomplete pairs");
            return;
        }

        double output = Convert.ToDouble(Operation.mult(input));
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded 'C:\Users\Guitar God\Documents\CS\calculator\bin\Debug\net5.0\calculator.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Enter input: 
5x5
```

```
Enter input:
5x5
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at FindParse.find_parse(String str) in \main.cs:line 137
   at Calculator.Main() in \main.cs:line 166
```

Comment: Sure would help if you told us which line is throwing the exception.  Arrays are zero based, so something like this `for (int i = 0; i == str.Length; ++i)` doesn't look right.

Comment: Are you asking what's causing the exception, or are you asking why the console isn't showing it? If you want the built console program to show it (so, not debug mode), you need to add try/catch and handle it. Otherwise, it's unhandled and will just crash things. Debug mode is a little more lenient and the exceptions just show up in output, depending on your settings.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Why it isn't showing the exception.

Comment: Ah, I see. As this is a question about an IDE, it might get better traction over on superuser, but [here's the basics for debugging with vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). I'm more a Visual Studio person, so I'm not sure if you're asking why it's not displaying the exception in the debug output window, or why it's not breaking on the exception. Or maybe you see it not having an exception at all...